# How to trigger an event from hubot console?

Tags: hubot

I am trying to debug and play with hubot from the hubot console.

Hubot scripts react to messages written in the hubot console.

So if I have a script like this:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /hi/, (msg) ->
    msg.send "hi guy"
```

And within my hubot console I write "hubot hi", then hubot will repond like so:

```
$hubot> hubot hi
$hubot> hi guy
```

My question is how can I do the same with events (`robot.on`).

As in if I have code like this:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.on "github-repo-event", (event) ->
    console.log "grrrr, I'm triggered"
```

Then how would I trigger this event from the hubot console?

Is there something like this ....?

```
$hubot> hubot trigger-event:github-repo-event
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing I found I can do is add a script that emits the event I want.

So add something like this:

```
# debug-script.coffee

module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /debug-github-repo-event/, (msg) ->
  robot.emit 'github-repo-event', eventData
```

Then from the console you can achieve this

```
$hubot> hubot debug-github-repo-event
$hubot> grrrr, I'm triggered
```

I don't like this but it works.

I didn't want to create an adapter that adds events to the shell adapter.